# Pair elements from two different Arrays into a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Let's say I have this two Arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

What I want to get is a Hash as follows:

```
c = { 1 => [1, 6], 2 => [2, 7], 3 => [3, 8], 4 => [4, 9], 5 => [5, 10] }
```

The only way I've come across so far is as follows:

```
# Initialize the resulting Hash and fill in the keys.
c = {}
(a.length).times { |i| c[i + 1] = [] }

# Fill values
c.each_with_index do |(key), idx|
  c[key] = [a[idx], b[idx]]
end
```

Does Ruby have a better or pretty way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functional approach:

```
Hash[a.zip(b).map.with_index(1) { |pair, idx| [idx, pair] }]
#=> {1=>[1, 6], 2=>[2, 7], 3=>[3, 8], 4=>[4, 9], 5=>[5, 10]}
```

Just for fun, and if you like to build your own abstractions: the previous snippet is more verbose than it should because of `with_index`, firstly it works only on enumerators (not enumerables), secondly it puts the value as the second element (it would be more useful as the first, that's what most of other languages do). What could we do? add our own `Enumerable#indexed` method that worked the other way around. At this point we'd be compelled to also add `Enumerable#to_h`, so finally we'd be able to write this pure OOP, left-to-right, declarative code:

```
a.zip(b).indexed(1).to_h
```

Comment: @sawa: Nope, but I am not sure why.

Comment: I see. I was wrong. I figured out why. When using `to_proc` and the block takes multiple block arguments, the first one becomes the receiver and the rest the arguments.

Comment: @sawa @tokland Interesting. `Hash[ a.zip(b).map.with_index(1).to_a.map &:reverse ]` gives it, but `Enumerator#map &:reverse` gives error. Looking for explanation.

Comment: @jokester Right after `with_index`, the enumerator is capable of giving two block arguments. `to_a` changes that into one object.

Answer (score 8):

```
c = Hash[(1..a.size).zip(a.zip(b))]
```

This takes advantage of [Hash's key-value pair initializer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

Comment: +1 a double `zip` is slight less declarative but I also like it. IMHO the problem is that indexations in Ruby are wrong, they are more useful as the first element, not the last. And then we could write `Hash[a.zip(b).indexed(1)]` or something like that.

Comment: Or in your special case, where a contains the keys, even shorter
`Hash[a.zip(a.zip(b))]`

Answer (score 0):

> Does Ruby have a better or pretty way to this?

Of course, it does!

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

c = a.zip(b).each.with_index.with_object({}) do |(arr, idx), memo|
  memo[idx + 1] = arr
end

c # => {1=>[1, 6], 2=>[2, 7], 3=>[3, 8], 4=>[4, 9], 5=>[5, 10]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got a number of great answers. I will add two more just for diversity.

```
Hash[(0...a.size).map{ |i| [i+1, [a[i], b[i]]] } ]
```

or

```
(0...a.size).each_with_object({}) { |i, h| h[i+1] = [a[i], b[i]] }
```

I would argue that the versions are easier to read and understand. :) However, that's a matter of taste.

**UPDATE:**

I caaaaaannot stop. :-) Here is one more:

```
a.zip(b).each_with_object({}) { |p, h| h[h.size+1] = p }
```